# Как выделить ново-созданный Item ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Дело в том, что нужно выделить или поменять `background` item на 5 секунд, чтобы пользователь видел какой пункт появился. Перерыл везде, не могу найти ответ везде выделение при клике... 
Заранее спасибо...

Comment: Насколько мне помниться в `RecyclerView` есть уже готовые дефолтные анимации на вставку, удаление и перемещение айтемов (их можно поменять и на свои). отвечают за это методы адаптера: `notifyItemInserted()`, `notifyItemMoved()`, `notifyItemRemoved()` - возможно это решение будет более подходящим.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я использовал такое решение

1) Использую class для хранения данных ListView

```
        public class ArrayGroup {

            private String name;
            private boolean isNew;  //именно здесь храню признак нового элемента 

            public ArrayGroup(String name, boolean isNew) {
                this.name = name;
                this.isNew = isNew;
            }

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

            public boolean isNew() {
                return isNew;
            }

            public void setNew(boolean aNew) {
                isNew = aNew;
            }
        }
```

2) Создаю адаптер:

```
public class AdapterGroup extends BaseAdapter {


                Context cont;
                LayoutInflater lInflater;
                ArrayList<ArrayGroup> objects;

                AdapterGroup(Context context, ArrayList<ArrayGroup> mylist){
                    cont= context;
                    objects= mylist;
                    lInflater=(LayoutInflater) cont.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                }

                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                    return objects.size();
                }

                @Override
                public Object getItem(int position) {
                    return objects.get(position);
                }

                @Override
                public long getItemId(int position) {
                    return position;
                }

                @Override
                public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View view = convertView;
                    if (view == null) {
                        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
                    }

                    ArrayGroup p = ((ArrayGroup) getItem(position));
                    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(p.getName());

                    if(p.isNew()){    //АНИМАЦИЯ ЕСЛИ НОВЫЙ
                        p.setNew(false);  //Снимаем флаг нового

    //   ******** В ЭТОМ МЕСТЕ АНИМАЦИЕЙ ОТМЕЧАЙТЕ ВАШ НОВЫЙ ЭЛЕМЕНТ



                AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0.4f, 0.9f);
                            alphaAnimation.setDuration(3000);
                            alphaAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
                            alphaAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
                            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setAnimation(alphaAnimation);  //ДЕЛАЙТЕ С ЭЛЕМЕНТОМ ListView что угодно
//Можете изменить backGround и в новом потоке через х секунд вернуть backGround
                        }
                        return view;
                    }
            }


            В Activity все просто
            public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
            Button btnAdd;
            AdapterGroup adapter;
            ArrayList<ArrayGroup> items = new ArrayList<ArrayGroup>();
            ListView listView;


            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                adapter = new AdapterGroup(this, items);
                listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);


                btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
                btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        items.add(new ArrayGroup("Hello! "+new Date().toString(), true));
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
            }
  }
```

Comment: можно просто в конструкторе `ArrayGroup` инициализировать `isNew`, зачем параметром то передавать - при создании объекта будет `true`

Comment: Затем pavloff что ArreyGroup может быть заполнен сотней элементов и выведен, а добавлен и проанимирован только один должен. По вашей логике  pavloff получится, что при первом запуске все элементы окажутся новыми и анимация пойдет по всему списку. Код который я предоставил уже успешно опробован